# How does vector range constructor work in the below class?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

In the below class -

```
class my_string_adapter
{
   string s;
   public:
   my_string_adapter(const string& s):s(s){}


   vector<my_string_adapter> break_strings_into_vector(const string delimiter =" ") const
   {
      string s_lo = boost::to_lower_copy(s);
      vector<string> parts;
      boost::split(parts,s_lo,boost::is_any_of(delimiter),boost::token_compress_on);
      return vector<my_string_adapter>(parts.begin(),parts.end());
   } 

};
```

How does `vector<my_string_adapter>(parts.begin(),parts.end())`  Type casting work from string to class . In what all cases does this casting of vector range constructor work.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think question maybe slightly same , but the answer of constructor of my_string_adapter acting as conversion constructor is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor `my_string_adapter(const string& s)` is a so-called *conversion* constructor. It can be used for implicit conversion from a `std::string` to a `my_string_adapter` object.

When the code do

```
vector<my_string_adapter>(parts.begin(),parts.end())
```

then for each `std::string` object in the vector `parts`, a new `my_string_adapter` object is created for the resulting vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<my_string_adapter>(parts.begin(),parts.end());
```

constructs a vector the same size as `parts` which each element of the new vector being constructed from the corresponding element of `parts`. In other words the `my_string_adapter(const string&)` constructor is used to convert each element of `parts` to a new vector.